# clearing all query strings / url parameters php but using values

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

From what I understand it is possible to get query strings and clean up the url afterwards.

I basically want to send a user a link containing many types of data to build up a special page for them and afterwards clean up the url to hide the mess. I would mainly use the parameters to load certain products etc.

What would be the best way going about this? And is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not inherently possible. You'll always need to store the original information somewhere and redirect to a new *clean* url. At that url (new request) you'll need to be able to identify which of the previously stored information needs to be used (e.g. session, db-storage + token).

Comment: Thank you @Yoshi. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is use two functions/links instead for this. First function/link will be that user will click and store those values in a session and transfer it to other neat URL .

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Tristan.L, thanks , there may be other easy ways also, this is just wht i thought or how i have used.